# Jpa-Jpql Query to Select All field from parent Entity and specific field from child Entity in OneToOneMapping

Tags: spring-boot, join, spring-data-jpa, spring-data, jpql

I have oneToOne RelationShip between Employee and student entity i want to fetch all field from Employee Entity and name and modelNumber From Laptop Entity

**Employee Entity**

```
public class Employee {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
private Long id;

@Column(name = "employee_name")
private String name;

@Column(name = "date_of_birth")
private String dob;

@Column(name = "gender")
private char gender;

@Column(name = "skills")
private String[] skills;

@OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinColumn(name = "laptop_id")
private Laptop laptop;

 //getter setter
```

**Laptop Entity**

```
@Entity
public class Laptop {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
private Long id;

private String name;

private String ram;

private String modelNumber;

private String processor;

//getter Setter
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select e.id, e.name, e.dob, e.gender, e.skills, 
       e.laptop.name, e.laptop.modelNumber 
from Employee e
```

Please start by reading the docs: https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.4/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#hql